# how to configure and use jstl in websphere

Tags: websphere, jstl

Does anybody know how to configure jstl in websphere. i know that we have use taglib directive in web.xml . where do i find web.xml in websphere 5.1.2 and how to add the configuration.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to modify `web.xml` at all. Some poor online tutorials indeed suggests that, but you must never take everything at the interwebs for serious. Especially not roseindia.net and consorts.

To install JSTL, all you basically need to do are the following *two* steps:

1. Download [this file](http://archive.apache.org/dist/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2.zip), unzip, browse to `/lib` and put **both** `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` in the webapp's runtime classpath.
2. Declare any of the taglibs as per the [JSTL documentation](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) in top of JSP file. For example [JSTL core](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html):

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   ```

That's all. The default webapp's runtime classpath covers under each `Webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Just drop the JAR's in there.