# Does IBM Websphere 5.1.2 support jstl

Tags: java, jstl

Guys i have included jstl and standard.jar in lib directory under classpath. It says absolute uri http://java.sun.com/jstl is not found either in web.xml or in application. please let me know how to configure in websphere 5.1.2

Comment: looks like duplicate of your earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424360/how-to-configure-and-use-jstl-in-websphere. did you follow the exact steps mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The right taglib URI depends on the JSTL version. Assuming you're using [JSTL 1.1](http://mirror.uoregon.edu/apache/jakarta/taglibs/standard/binaries/jakarta-taglibs-standard-1.1.2.zip) (which would be the best choice for WAS 5.1.2 which runs Servlet 2.3), you need to specify taglib URI's as per [this document](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/). So, [JSTL core](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) should be specified as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

(note the extra `/jsp` path; this is added in JSTL 1.1 as opposed to JSTL 1.0)